# CV2 saves pictures in BlackNWhite

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, opencv3.0, opencv

I'm trying to send a picture with `sockets` module and `pickles`. It goes ok, but received picture is a bnw... could someone please tell me, which part I'm doing wrong?

first set parameters:

```
encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY)]
```

read the file

```
img = cv2.imread('th.jpg', 0)
```

encode it

```
 ret, img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img, encode_param)
```

dump and after that send it with `pickles` to my `client` side

```
 msg = pickle.dumps(img, 0)
```

on my `client side` - open it, decode it and write to file

```
        frame=pickle.loads(message, fix_imports=True, encoding="bytes")
        frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imwrite(f'{message_header}.jpg',frame)
```

but the saved file is bnw.... Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with this line. `img = cv2.imread('th.jpg', 0)` change it to the following.

`img = cv2.imread('th.jpg', 1)`

According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#read-an-image), argument `0` in `imread` relates to grayscale and `1` relates to colour image.

Comment: thanks, this worked, but the picture's graphic became terrible... it looks a very pixelized now... sockets problem or cv?

Comment: okay, it was a socket problem, there was too much data to send with default quality 95 and RGB, so I lowered it to 70 and it works fine